# Red Hat needs-restarting

Tags: redhat, restart, reboot

I have some problems trying to test "needs-restarting -r ; echo $?" inside a RedHat distribution. The command works for cases where a reboot is not required, but I have not been able to voluntarily generate the need to reboot in the operating system, which has made it impossible for me to know if the response to the command works. That is to say the output in 1 of the needs-restarting. Do you know of any way to generate the need to reboot in a controlled manner in RedHat?

Answer (score 0):

You can find which packages require a system reboot after the update to [Redhat KB](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27943). If you can downgrade one of these packages, you can generate reboot required state. But this is not recommended in production systems. glibc and kernel downgrades can cause problems. You can try it at new installed Rhel server after "yum update".